# OS X Set Screen Size Manually

Tags: macos, display, vnc, applescript

I wish to **increase the size** of an **application window** like TextEdit to be **greater** than the actual **screen height** but it is always limited by the screen size pixels.

Is there a way to artificially increase the screen size so that application windows have more room to increase their height? Perhaps using a VNC connection where screen height and width can be chosen.

Comment: I've read that thread already and the requirements are different. Neither of the two applications suggested allow me to set the screen size manually.

Comment: It still appears to be the same question.  Perhaps edit your question to explain how it's different than the possible dupe?

Comment: I have boldened where the two questions differ. Please see update. Even if the question is a duplicate (which it isn't!) - the other question is from a year ago with no correct answer.

Comment: Please explain what you want to accomplish and what it has to do with VNC.

Comment: I thought by using VNC I could change screen size. In the same way, if you connected a large screen you'll have more screen real estate. What I'm trying to achieve is the second paragraph of my question.

Comment: Excellent a non duplicate is closed. To make matters worse, the possible duplicate link doesn't have an answer and is a year old. I can't help thinking there is a flaw here.

Comment: You can flag for moderator attention to have it reopened. But even after your edit your question is difficult to understand, maybe try editing before flagging. How's VNC relevant here, and why does the other question not apply? Also, fix the second sentence in your question, it doesn't make any sense ( to me at least)

Comment: I have edited my question is it clearer? Your answer was very close and it shows you understand the question but now I have rewritten it such that the question makes no assumptions.

Comment: Yes, now it's quite clear. That VNC part didn't make sense to me before, and I see now it was just your approach to a possible solution. Do you have two screens connected to your Mac? If you do, you can arrange them diagonally from each other and resize windows to the "full square" size, i.e. opposing quarters of the window will not be visible but could be screens hotted. *(Please do not move this to chat!)*

Comment: @DanielBeck good idea, I am about to try that. I think that will work - surely! Have to unpack my old screen for this!

Comment: Let me know if it works so I can add that to my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'n not sure I understand the question, but starting with OS X Lion, it's possible to increase window height beyond screen height.

---

1. Select * » Dock » Position on left* (somewhat optional, but it makes the following steps easier).
2. Drag the window you want to resize to the bottom of the screen, so that only the title bar is visible.
3. Resize the window at the top border (possible since OS X 10.7) and drag that edge to the menu bar.

It will look like this:

> [image]

But the window is actually much higher:

> [image]

---

If you move the window afterwards, its height is reduced to available screen height again.

Comment: Yes, you've understood the problem. Unfortunately, I am on snow leopard. That's interesting though, so on Lion when you resize a window it makes it larger at both ends? I've been attempting to resize using applescript `set bounds of window 1 to {10, 10, 1024, 3000}` but it is always limited.

Comment: @abs no, but you move the window down to below the screen edge. Lion allows resizing like windows at every screen edge, so you resize it to the top of the screen while the hidden part stays put below. That way you can achieve almost 2x screen height for a window. Applescript still doesn't work, and as I wrote, moving the window will resize to within screen bounds.

Comment: @abs I remember that it was possible to resize windows quite nicely when having multiple screens with skewed relative positions. Maybe that's an option for you?

Comment: I just tried using two screen, and arrange so that they were on top of each other and I also tried diagonally but my apple script always was limited by the screen! I could move windows through each screen but not resize it via applescript! Any ideas?

Comment: @Abs Try resizing via window handle.

Comment: How do you mean? A window handle in objective-c? The window that I am trying to auto resize is TextEdit or even Safari.

Comment: @Abs The requirement to do this programmatically is new and was never stated in your question. By "handle" I mean that small rectangle in the lower right corner of your window. Use the mouse to resize beyond screen boundaries.

Comment: That won't let you go past the bottom of the screen. The mouse is also limited by that boundary.

Comment: @Abs In *System Preferences » Displays*, arrange your two screens so one is on the upper left, the other on the lower right. Then you can resize a window on the upper left screen onto the lower right screen using the window grab handle.

Comment: yes, I am able to do that manually with my mouse with no problems. However, with apple-script it always stops at the bottom of one screen.In addition, there is no way to click and drag in apple script. Using the "Extra Suites" you can only click and double click but not click and hold and drag! I'm thinking of buying a bigger screen to achieve this but that sounds silly and I need to solve this pro-grammatically, I'm at wits end!

Comment: @Abs You really should mention the requirement that this be solved programmatically in the question. And maybe it's more appropriate on StackOverflow then -- consider having a moderator migrate this question over to where the Objective-C developers are ;)

Comment: I have a programmatic version of it on SO already but no good answers. That's why I thought it can be solved by using VNC or changing some setting using some osx software but its starting to turn into a programmatic question again!

Comment: @Abs Well, you're asking for a way to turn your programmatic AppleScript approach into a working solution — that's why my answer doesn't work for you. Good luck getting an answer you find useful!